# References within an azure functions project not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So I have some Azure Functions I need to publish, which I want to do via a functions project. However, those functions rely on references to class libraries within my solution, and the references do not work within a functions project, is there a way around this?

Edit: After adding the references to the other projects, when "using" the namespaces in which the classes are kept, the compiler throws an error "cannot resolve symbol", it is as if the reference does not exist. The functions project will not build because it cannot find the namespace in which the classes exist

Comment: what do you mean by 'do not work'? What error do you get? compile time/runtime? Please provide some more information

Comment: So after adding the references to the other projects, when "using" the namespaces in which the classes are kept, the compiler throws an error "cannot resolve symbol", it is as if the reference does not exist

Comment: Something is wrong with your project setup. Which VS version / project template are you using?

Comment: Using VS2017 v15.4.1 and an Azure Functions project template

Comment: The process here doesn't really differ from standard references in a class library. Are you able to reference those assemblies from a simple class library  project targeting .NET 4.6.1? More details about the exact error you're seeing would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that each project targets the same version of .NET framework. I had the same problem until I noticed that the referenced project targeted 4.7.1, but my Azure function project targeted 4.6.1. Changing the referenced project to match the Azure function project resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @nmarler, I had the same issue and you saved me a lot of debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple more steps to consume assemblies if they're not exposed by default in Azure Functions. If it's a custom assembly you have to make sure it's included in the bin folder. Then you have to make sure you're using the `#r` directive. Are you doing both of those things? Include your code header and settings if so.

This page has the list of assemblies that are visible to Azure Functions, some still requiring the `#r` directive:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies

> The following assemblies are automatically added by the Azure Functions hosting environment:
>   mscorlib
>   System
>   System.Core
>   System.Xml
>   System.Net.Http
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions
>   System.Web.Http
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting
>
> The following assemblies may be referenced by simple-name (for
>   example, #r "AssemblyName"): Newtonsoft.Json
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage Microsoft.ServiceBus
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Common
>   Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs

Comment: Your answer does not apply for precompiled functions created in Visual Studio

Comment: I may have misunderstood. I read the OP to mean he is trying to deploy functions that reference precompiled assemblies. Fair point if that's not the case.